# Does AWS Cognito Token endpoint origin have to match Auth endpoint origin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito federated through Google.

I am trying to use the Authorization Code Grant flow, which requires making two requests.

1. `/oauth2/auth`

The first request is to get the authorization code, which is then sent as part of the second request. This request comes back fine.

2. `/oauth2/token`

This request accepts the authorization code from the first, and *should* return the appropriate tokens.

However, this endpoint requires a secret in the header, so I have created an API (to not expose the secret to the client) that accepts the token and makes the request from a different origin as the first request. For example, the first request is made from `example.com`, while the second is from `api.example.com`. This fails with the error message: `400: invalid request`. But, if I take the exact same code from the API, and put it in the client directly (with the secret), it returns the appropriate tokens. The only difference I can think of is the origin. Is there a way around this or is this just not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, forgot to stringify the data as part of the request on the server-side. Thanks.